# Configuring dynamically provisioned Docker agents

Tags: docker, jenkins, agent

I run a jenkins container but I'd like to Configuring dynamically provisioned Docker agents and I installed docker plugin on jenkins. However I can't reach docker inside the container even if I changed /lib/systemd/system/docker.service turning:

ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

into

ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375

and I restart teh daemon with:

sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo service docker restart.

After that I went to jenkins configuration and created docker cloud.

the fact is that when I test tcp://172.17.0.1:2375 in docker cloud details it doesn't work. I test in the container ping 172.17.0.1 and the container reaches that host.

Did I miss something?

Comment: What do you mean by `reach docker inside the container`? What your change is just just enable the remote visit of docker engine, didn't see any relationship with your question.

Comment: I meant that if a have a regular installation I can use cloud in jenkins to create docker containers on the fly to use a pipeline. Ho can I do to do the same with a dockerized Jenkins? I can reach docker server on my host environment by using a jenkins container instead of a jenkins regular installation?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is `access docker daemon from docker container`:

1. Add `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` when start jenkins container.
2. Add `-v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker` mount to jenkins container, or download related docker prebuilt client from https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/, see [this](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/binaries/#install-static-binaries).

With `1`, the container will be able to connect to docker daemon and new sibling container, with `2`, your jenkins container will have `docker client` available. You may also want to have a look for [this](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/).

Comment: But in this way I have to launch the container as root because otherwise docker doesn't accept connection on the socket:


Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

Comment: What about add `-u jenkins:$(cut -d: -f3 < <(getent group docker))` when start the jenkins container?

Comment: I launched the container as root but nothing.

When I try on my host curl http:// 172.17.0.1:2375/version I get it, but when I try inside the container there is no answer even if I use docker cli it works. How can I reach tpc://172.17.0.1:2375 from the container?

Comment: root@3812f8e2aace:/# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
3812f8e2aace        jenkins/jenkins:2.176.3   "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    50000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9090->8080/tcp   jenkins
----------------
root@3812f8e2aace:/# curl http://127.0.0.1:2375
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 2375: Connection refused

Comment: I create a nginx container listen at port 80 and I use a tutum/curl to get it and it works. But when I try to perform a curl to docker address nothing happens whereas in local I get the endpoint /version.

Answer (score 0):

The container by default are launched by a bridge network. It was enough declare in docker run the option --network=host.